# Want to set wordpress website's page title

Tags: wordpress

In My wordpress website's page titles are start with >> symbol I want to remove that >> symbol so please help me..
and I'm using wordpress-seo plugin after that this problem is occuring

Comment: actually I want to share image of that title but my reputation is week so I cant..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify your theme to do that.

Most likely you have to modify the `header.php` file using the [wordpress theme editor](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_Files#Using_the_Theme_Editor_and_Plugin_Editor).
Find the line where `wp_title` is called and call it with an empty string as first parameter.
When `wp_title` is called without any parameters it adds the leading `&raquo;` (») by default.

You can also trim the result of `wp_title` to avoid leading and trailing whitepspace.

Take a look at the following links too:

- http://www.onlinenerd24.de/2008/09/29/remove-the-from-your-wordpress-title/
- http://cuongdang.info/how-to-remove-the-arrows-%C2%BB-from-wordpress-titles.html
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title (take a look at the $sep param)

Comment: I use this code <?php trim(wp_title("")); ?>  but still same problem

Comment: ok Thanks a lot @Nick Russler actually I remove &raquo; then my problem is solved